# jsf2 inherited controller with cdi not working - Target Unreachable

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, cdi, java-ee-7

I have some common properties and functionality in controllers which are sessionscoped like following

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class DemoController implements Serializable {

 ...
}
```

This works properly, in the jsf where I do

```
<f:viewParam name="lang" vlaue="#{demoController.language}" />
```

But when I move some common properties to a BaseBase controller .. and do like this

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class DemoController extends BaseController {

 ...
}
```

I immediately get

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'demoController' resolved to null
```

Is it not possible to inherit ManagedBeans like this ? I have other cdi beans which are inherited and @injected, they work properly.

*EDIT*

Here is the code for BaseController

```
public class BaseController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7581824370592944659L;

    protected String language;

    @Inject
    protected SessionsUtil sessionsUtil;

    public String getLanguage () {

        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage (String language) {

        this.language = language;
    }

    public void init() {

        if (null != language) {

            sessionsUtil.switchLanguage(language.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

PS: The app is deployed in glassfish 4

Comment: This should work, please add your code of the `BaseController`.

Comment: Strange stuff...there is a typo in your XHTML but I guess you already got that. Maybe you can try with exactly the same classes as you described: a `BaseController` which holds all attributes and a `DemoController` which only extends the `BaseController` and adds the annotations.

Comment: Do you have any errors earlier in the log? There is a chance server had troubles instantiating your controller

Comment: No. Nothing special in the log. I have to anyway upgrade mojarra because of another bug related to view params. So I will give this a try after the upgrade.

Comment: narrowing a problem could help finding the cause. Try to comment '@Inject' see what happens. Or try to change @Named with '@ManagedBean' and see if the problem remains. Based on information you will get you might be able to move forward

Comment: Somehow it started working with the new mojarra version 2.2.6, previously I had the version which is bundled with glassfish4. This is really strange.